# phpMyAdmin Import .txt file?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, text-files

I received a database in this format:

```
FB_BRANDID|FB_MODELID|FB_TEXTID|FB_TEXT|FB_TYPEID|FB_COUNTRYID
19|5783|38742|mn_4x4_synchrone_l.jpg|10|1
19|5783|38744|mn_4x4_synchrone_s.jpg|11|1
... and so on
```

Is there any way to imprt that in my MySQL database?  I am using phpMyAdmin.  From what I can see, it won't allow me to import that kind of file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible via phpMyAdmin.

Import a CSV-file, but replace the semicolon with the pipe |. Empty the input "Fields enclosed by" and check the box "Column names in first row".